# throw an error when $match doesn't find any matching doc

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   loginAttempts: [ { IP: String } ]
})
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'users')
```

```js
app.get('/users/:userId/login-attempts', async(req,res,next)=>{
    const loginAttempt = await User.aggregate([
        { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId) } },
        { $unwind: '$loginAttempts' },
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$loginAttempts' } },
    ])
})
```

I want when the operator `$match` does not find a matching document to throw an error to report something at least, to show the client a real message that the `req.params.id` he's looking for does not exist in the first stage.

But how?

Comment: you can not do it in query, you have to do it outside query, by checking variable `loginAttempt` has any elements or not.

Comment: @turivishal But loginAttempts by default is an empty array, so, if the array was empty, this doesn't mean that there's no user. and the aggregate function above returns an empty array if it did not find anything, so how to differentiate in this case?

Comment: There is no straight way to check this inside the mongodb query.